# How can I use a SQL view to write a pandas dataframe to a SQL table from within python?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a dataframe in my python program with columns corresponding to a table on my SQL server. I want to append the contents of my dataframe to the SQL table. Here's the catch: I'm not permissioned to access the SQL table itself, I can only interact with it through a view.

I know if I could write directly to the table I could use SQL alchemy's to_sql function. However, I can only use a view to write to the table in the database.

Is this even possible? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You *can* update tables via `VIEW`s, but only if it's a simple `VIEW`. Otherwise the `VIEW` has to have a `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER`, however, this in truth seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @Larnu how can you update a table via a view? genuinely curious do you mean inserting the query set from a view into a table via a proc/trigger?

Comment: Provided it's a simple view, so references a single table, just run the `INSERT`/`UPDATE` against the `VIEW`, @Manakin. [db<>fidde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=eeb0280559217aee737aed67d2cc5b24)

Comment: @Larnu thanks, that makes sense. However, strongly gives off the smell of an anti pattern!

Comment: I didn't say it was a *good* idea, @Manakin , just that you can do it. ;)

Comment: Also, as I alluded to, you can do it on non-simplistic views, but that involves triggers, @Manakin . Though I'm not writing an example for that. :)